# How does one access sheets of Excel Workbook using R in Power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi

Background:
I am in a Business role and have been creating dashboards for my team to see sales KPIs along with other Sales related data in dashboards. Now, the Dashboards themselves are done and now I am going back to make them much more scaleable and forward-thinking for when my successor in my role inevitably does not have the skills that I have in R and Python.

Problem:
For this reason, I have what I think is a super basic Power BI question for those who have more expertise than myself. How do I go about allowing a user to load in an excel workbook with 3 sheets, and access the dataset to pull the sheets and manipulate them using R within Power BI?

Basically I have been trying to access the `dataset` object in Power BI and cannot figure out have to read in sheets of a workbook from this file. I figure it would be much easier to do it this way then to have someone in my role in the future adjust the path to the files within my R script when they will most likely have no knowledge of coding or R. I have tried subsetting the data with brackets and using the $ to access the sheets but it has not worked.

Comment: Can Power BI use non-base R packages? If so, look into [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) or [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html). Or is it your intent to use non-R methods to access the data?

Comment: I would assume creating an `R` script with the appropriate [home directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-r-scripts) and using `readxl` (available according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-r-packages-support)) would do the trick. Albeit i have very limited experience with R in a PowerBI context.

Comment: This there anything that R offers that Power BI cannot do for your dataset. Pulling data in from sheets and doing sales kpis etc, seem to use the basic functions of Power BI. If you wish to deploy this to the Power BI Service you will be limited to the R packages you can use

Comment: Yes, power BI can use non-base R packages. When running the script, it runs it based on what is on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I actually figured it out. What you have to do is expand the tables within the worksheet so that all the sheets are on one table.

After you do that, Power BIA adds a column with the sheet name to it. Then it is as easy as sub setting the data so that each sheet is a subset of the expanded table.